# Can contextual drop-down menu replace menu tabs?

Tags: 7, routes, navigation, views

When I am viewing stuff I have admin rights to the tabbed menu with stuff like 'View | Edit | Outline | etc ' takes up too much space.

Is there a way to switch drop down menus similar to those used for blocks?

Comment: Simple answer is yes. But would require quite a bit of coding.

Answer (score 1):

[Contextual tabs module](https://drupal.org/project/contextual_tabs) used in Open Atrium distribution seems to be exactly for that:

> Moves the normal Drupal primary tabs into a drop-down "contextual links" menu to the right of the node title.

Screenshot:
[image: Contextual tabs screenshot]

Comment: I don't recommend this one. It is based on https://drupal.org/sandbox/onkeltem/1730244 and has been modified to be dependent on using a Bootstrap theme, a fact which is only noted at the end of the project's page.

It is not named properly in the module list. A name like `Tabs No More` belongs in the sandbox not production.


 The sandbox version works with all themes and the only flaw is it doesn't show all the Contextual links in Display mode. It would be better to fix that one first and create a submodule for Bootstrap


It ought to return to the sandbox. Pretty annoying actually.

Comment: I voted it up because it works for with Bootstrap themes, but I can't recommend it for every one